# How to Redirect to a Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0

I am using OAuth in an ASP.net app using the usual VS template.

One of the option in StartUp.Auth is: `TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),`

This works fine when the client calls it and it logs the person in as expected.

However, in some cases, the user logs in with a different flow.  In that case, I call a Web API Controller and do some processing to find the username and password, and then I want to do a redirect to "/Token"

I have tried:

```
 return this.RedirectToRoute("/Token", new { userName = externalUser.UserId, password = externalUser.Password });
```

But it throws an error: "A route named '/Token' could not be found in the route collection."

How do I do this redirect?

The other way to resolve this would be to figure out how to call `ApplicationOAuthProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()` directly instead of calling the redirect, but I am not familiar enough with the workings of OAuth to figure that out.

Comment: Is Token an action method to which you want to redirect ?

Comment: I don't know: It's managed by the Owin Middleware.

Comment: `But it throws an error: "A route named '/Token' could not be found in the route collection."` => sure, the `'Token'` route is inside another middleware, not in the same routing as your mvc app. Why can you not be able to authentication inside `ApplicationOAuthProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()`?

Comment: Because the middleware calls this method, and it passes in a parameter that is required, but I don't know where it is gotten from.  This is the method:  `public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)`

Comment: It's from the request body. Something like this: `grant_type=password&username=testUserName&password=TestPassword`